# SimpleDateFormat and Date Comparison not given correct ouput

Tags: java, android

```
try {
            Date sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(_sysDate);
            Date userDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(_userDate);
            if (userDate.compareTo(sysDate) > 0)
                return false;
                    else 
                            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Above is my following code snippet to check two dates which is greater or not.
When I am giving :
sysdate=12/9/2012 and userdate=11/9/2012 or 10/8/2012 or 15/9/2011 it is giving the correct output

But when I am giving :
sysdate=12/9/2012 and userdate=13/8/2012 or 15/7/2012 or 16/6/2012 it is giving incorrect output. 
To my analysis I have come to this point if I choose any month between Jan' 12 to Aug '12 and select the day_of_month(i.e. 0,1,2,...,31) more than the current day_of_month (in this case 12), I always get an incorrect output.

Please suggest any possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the pattern which should be "dd/MM/yyyy" (with capital "MM" for month) instead of "dd/mm/yyyy" (with small "mm" which means minutes).

So, it should be as follows -

```
try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date sysDate = df.parse(_sysDate);  
    Date userDate = df.parse(_userDate);
    //...
```

Comment: It might be worth elaborating on this to explain how the current string is being used - i.e. it's filling in the *minutes* instead of months.

Comment: @BheshGurung : Except you've also shown `mm` instead of `MM` in your code example.

Comment: @Squonk: Thanks for pointing that out. Don't know how I missed it. But if I were you then I would just go ahead edit the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
            Date sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(_sysDate);
            Date userDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(_userDate);
            if (userDate.compareTo(sysDate) > 0)
                return false;
                    else 
                            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Date pattern is wrong **dd/MM/yyyy** instead of **dd/mm/yyyy**.

Answer (score -3):

see this data format change like this `dd/MM/yyyy` in place of dd/mm/yyyy.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Is that a comment or an answer ?

Comment: I see no indication that it would be useful as either.